Cant get all the fields in ViewData in a dotnet6 MVC application
I have an .net6 mvc application I am working on. jquery version 1.8.3.
In my controller I have this line:
 ViewData["CountryState"] = new SelectList(countryStates, "PK_StateID","StateName","FK_CountryID");

This is supposed to populate the chosen type dropdown for States. I would like the view to re-filter the States dropdown when the country is changed based on the PK_CountryID. I rather not make a call to the DB every time the country is changed.
My drop down is setup like this:
                <li class="columns three">
                <h3>@* @Resources.Common.Profile.Profile.Common_Profile_Country *@State</h3>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ResidentialStateId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CountryState"], "", new { @id = "drpEditIndContactResidencialCountryState", @class = "chzn-select width-175" })
            </li>

However when I look in the rendered HTML using F12 I see that only the first two fields are included. for example:
                   <h3>State</h3>
                    <select class="chzn-select width-175" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ResidentialStateId field is required." id="drpEditIndContactResidencialCountryState" name="ResidentialStateId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Badakhshan</option>
<option value="2">Badghis</option>
<option value="3">Baghlan</option>
<option value="4">Balkh</option>
<option value="5">Bamyan</option>
<option value="6">Daykundi</option>
<option value="7">Farah</option>
<option value="8">Faryab</option>
<option value="9">Ghazni</option>
<option value="10">Gh&#xC5;&#x8D;r</option>
<option value="11">Helmand</option>
<option value="12">Herat</option>
<option value="13">Jowzjan</option>
<option value="14">Kabul</option>

Would appreciate advise how to get the CountryID in their as well, so that when I change the country my filter state can filter the state based on the selected country.
Thank you


What's your class model like ? How do you define the country drop down list?

Hi @QingGuo, I added a screenshot of the viewdata that is being passed from .net to the question details

When SelectedValue is same with  dataValue (PK_StateID value)  , we can   selet the the datatextfield in the drop down. The "FK_CountryID" is a string, not match with the PK_StateID value.

Thank you @QingGuo, right now though I am just trying to get the data in the JS correctly so that I can even compare. I think I understood what you meant though I may be wrong. I added these lines:
var stateCountryId = $(this).data('SelectedValue');
var stateName = $(this).data('DataTextField');
var stateId = $(this).data('DataValueField');
console.log('State Country ID:', stateCountryId);
console.log('StateName:', stateName);
console.log('Country ID:', stateId);
I am still getting undefined logged as I loop though the list of states

It won't show 'SelectedValue' ,  the html like:  https://i.sstatic.net/MgFHg.png


I would like the view to re-filter the States dropdown when the
country is changed based on the PK_CountryID. I rather not make a call
to the DB every time the country is changed.

SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, String, Object)
Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text field, the data group field, and the selected value.
SelectList.SelectedValue Gets the list value that was selected by the user from sever,  not used for the filed "FK_CountryID" when select the country dropdown  .
If you don't want to  make a call to the DB every time the country is changed,  you need to put the  the countryStates in somewhere so that you can  re-filter the States dropdown when the country is changed .

how to get the CountryID in their as well

You can use jquery to get the CountryID  when select the country dropdown.
